# How to retrieve the underlying WPF UIElement from System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement object?

Tags: c#, wpf, automation, automated-tests, white-framework

I am implementing automated UI tests, using a well-known framework *TestStack.White*. So, it's pretty easy to lookup the desired *UIItem* by its *AutomationId*. Then I proceed to a property *AutomationElement*, and this is how the *System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement* object is obtained.

At this point I am wondering if there is any possibility to retrieve the "real" underlying *UIElement* (from *WPF*) of a given *AutomationElement* (from *System.Windows.Automation*). As far as I understand, the main idea is to decouple automation elements, used by tests, and their actual implementation, so that it all gets "UI framework independent". However, I still hope there exists some loophole, connecting those entities.

Comment: *"This is my first question here but I'll try to make it as concise as possible. "* -- That doesn't look to me like you're trying very hard.

Comment: So, for you "non-conciseness" comes down to usage of headers, neutral greetings and signatures, according to your amends? Did I get your comment right?

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages headers, footers, signatures, ritual greetings, and so on. We have a style of communication here that's preferred by the people who spend a lot of time answering questions for free.

Comment: Then developers of Stack Overflow are pretty skilled tempters as they provide users with a possibility to use headers in the text box for a question.
Anyway, thanks for a bit of enlightenment regarding local rules.

Comment: Good luck with your problem.